# Separating ALL duplicate observations from singles (300K observations)

Tags: r, function, duplicates, dplyr

I'm working with a large data set at the moment. I am looking at the water RightID # and trying to separate all duplicates from single rights. Duplicate rights are to be dealt with in a different manner than the single ones. I am using the dplyr package and have the following script written out so far.

```
# Change data to a tibble
tbl.all.rights <- tbl_df(rights$RightID)

# filter through duplicate rightIDs
# creates a new data frame with T for duplicate and F for non duplicate. 
log.dup <- data.frame(as.numeric(duplicated(tbl.all.rights)))
log.dup$RightID <- tbl.all.rights$value`
```

However, the duplicated function returns a FALSE value for the first duplicate because of the order in which the function goes through the vector.

```
>  e.g.) Duplicate  RightId
>               0      1000
>               0       999
>               1       999
>               1       999
```

I would like to preserve duplicate rights in their own data base. I was considering writing my own function to capture that first duplicate, and use that in conjunction with sapply. However, I'm having trouble writing that function. Any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: You may be misunderstanding `duplicated`: its role is to identify elements that *"are duplicates of elements with smaller subscripts"*. It is not intended to identify all that are not unique (which is what it appears you are expecting). You could try something like `... %>% group_by(RightId) %>% mutate(Duplicate = (n() > 1))`.

Comment: Use `duplicated(tbl.all.rights) | duplicated(tbl.all.rights, fromLast=TRUE)` in place of `duplicated(tbl.all.rights)`. This will pick up an element that is a duplicate.

Comment: @lmo That worked wonderfully! Thank you, very clever addition.